# Should this be giving a compile error?

Tags: typescript

The following compiles and runs just fine.  But it seems to me that the interface declaration says that the index should be of type number.  But I use a string here instead.

Is there a reason I don't get a compile error?

```
interface Dictionary {
[index: number] : string;
}

var dictionary : Dictionary = {};
dictionary["First"] = "apple";

console.log(dictionary["First"]);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a subtle thing about the index signatures. When using an interface with an index signature like:

```
[index: number] : string
```

That means that any time there is an index that is a `number`, that it must be set to a `string` value. It does not limit the object instance to only `number`s. When there is a number, it must be set to a `string`.

From the specification (3.7.4 Index Signatures currently):

> Numeric index signatures, specified using index type number, define
>   type constraints for all  numerically named properties in the
>   containing type. Specifically, in a type with a numeric index 
>   signature of type T, all numerically named properties must have types
>   that are subtypes of T.

If you were to change the interface to:

```
[index: number]: number;
```

And add a line:

```
dictionary[1] = "apple";
```

There will be a compile error: `"Cannot convert 'string' to 'number'."`

If the index signature doesn't match the property assignment in an object literal, it is processed without a contextual type (ignored without error), assuming it didn't match an actual property.