# TypeScript interface for object with arbitrary numeric property names?

Tags: typescript

I have an object where all the keys are numbers and all the values are strings, like this:

```
var object = {
    1: "whatever",
    7: "whateverrr",
    ...
};
```

Is there any way I can write a TypeScript interface for this? I don't know what all the keys will be, but I do know that they will be numbers and that the values will be strings so I feel like it should be possible to do some kind of type checking.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use an index signature to represent this:

```
interface NumberToString {
    [n: number]: string;
}

var x: NumberToString;
x = { 1: 42 }; // Error
x[1].charAt(0); // OK

x['foo'] = 'bar'; // Still not an error, though
```

Comment: Thanks! But why does it allow `x['foo'] = 'bar';`?

Comment: Long story, but basically because `x[1] === x['1']`, and `x['hasOwnProperty']` is still valid

Comment: @Jeremy -Might want to read this Q & A: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21960916/should-this-be-giving-a-compile-error/21961792#21961792