# How can I create an interface for a collection of objects?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following Javascript object:

```
{
   "dataMap":{
       "2027":{
          "userId":2027,
          "code":"abcdef",
          "title":"abcdef",
          "questions":1
       }
       "2028":{
          "userId":2028,
          "code":"abcdef",
          "title":"abcdef",
          "questions":1
       }
   }
}
```

It contains another object dataMap and inside that are other ojbects. Can someone help me by telling me how I can create an interface for the dataMap object?

What I would like is to have an interface so I can enter:

```
var a = b.dataMap[2027].userId // okay and allowed
var a = b.dataMap[2027].xxxyId // gives a typescript error
```

Comment: Please, clarify what you exactly mean by "interface"

Comment: @hindmost A Typescript interface obviously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an interface with an index signature:

```
interface User {
    userId: number;
    code: string;
    title: string;
    questions: number;
}

interface DataMap {
    [index: number]: User;
}
```

And for your specific example where the data map is again contained in an object:

```
interface DataMapContainer {
    dataMap: DataMap;
}

var b: DataMapContainer = { "dataMap": { ... } };
b.dataMap[2027].userId; // okay
b.dataMap[2027].xxx; // error
```

See also: [TypeScript interface for object with arbitrary numeric property names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22313876/typescript-interface-for-object-with-arbitrary-numeric-property-names)